# How to add conditional statement inside SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi I am working on one SQL query. Below is my method name which executes query.

```
private string GetAggregatedOptionParametersByStyleIdCommand(string styleId, bool currentStore)
    {
      SELECT
      opts.style, opts.option::text as {OptionKey}, opts.primary_colour, opts.secondary_colour, opts.brand_description, opts.description, params.*,
    CASE WHEN {currentStore} == true THEN 
    FROM
      rex.options opts
    JOIN
      rex.product_atoms atoms ON atoms.option_id = opts.option
    JOIN
      rex.parameters params ON atoms.id = params.product_atom_id
    JOIN
      rex.stores stores ON params.store = stores.id
    WHERE
      opts.style = '{styleId}'
  }
```

Below is the structure of stores table.

```
CREATE TABLE rex.stores (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    close_date timestamp NOT NULL,
    country text NULL,
    distribution_centre text NULL,
    "name" text NULL,
    open_date timestamp NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_stores" PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

So what I am trying to make is, Whenever the currentStore is true then I want to return the current store. Condition to check currentStore is

```
 store.OpenDate <= currentDate &&
          store.CloseDate >= currentDate
```

Whenever the currentStore is false I want to return all store. To check all store condition is

```
store.CloseDate >= currentDate
```

I am trying to add these conditions inside SQL query. I have added `CASE WHEN {currentStore} == true THEN` I am not sure how to add my closed store condition. Can anyone help me to complete this query? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What DBMS is this for? Judging by the `::` cast probably Postgres? And the language your function is in? C# maybe? Please add the appropriate tags, would you please?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for another possibility you can either add another `WHEN` or `ELSE` condition to your `CASE` statement. These need to come before the `END`.

For example:

```
CASE
    WHEN x < 0 THEN 'negative'
    WHEN x > 0 THEN 'positive'
    ELSE 'zero'
END
```

I am not familiar with postgres, you may not need an `END`, and you may also be able to say `CASE x WHEN > 0 THEN... WHEN < 0 ...` meaning you only need to mention x once after `CASE`; again, this may not be a thing in postgres.